# Using lapply over a list and adding a column with data frame name

Tags: r

I have a list containing two data frames:

```
sample_list <- list("tables" = data.frame(weight = sample(1:50, 20, replace = T)),
                    "chairs" = data.frame(height = sample(1:50, 20, replace = T)))
```

I would like to use `lapply` to run a function over all the data frames in this list. In the output of each function, I need to create another column with the name of the source data frame (see `mutate`):

```
lapply(sample_list, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    filter(x >= 20) %>% 
    mutate(groupName = names(x))
})
```

For some reason, I can't figure out how to make this work. How do I pass the name of the data frame into mutate? Right now it is returning the name of the first column in that data frame, rather than the name of the data frame itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`): `Map(function(df, nm) df %>% ... mutate(groupName = nm), sample_list, names(sample_list))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can loop through `names` of *sample_list* instead of looping through the list

```
lapply(names(sample_list), function(x) {
    sample_list[[x]] %>% 
        filter_at(vars(1),~. >= 20) %>% 
        mutate(groupName = x)
})
```

**Update Sep-2021**

cleaner way using `purrr::map`

```
purrr::map(names(sample_list), ~sample_list[[.x]] %>% 
             filter_at(vars(1),~. >= 20) %>% 
             mutate(groupName = .x)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `purrr::imap()` to map over both elements and elements' name.

```r
# purrr::imap
purrr::imap(sample_list, function(element,name){
    head(mutate(element,groupName = name))
})

# or mapply, but you need to specify names of the list
myfun <- function(element,name){
    head(mutate(element,groupName = name))
}

mapply(myfun,sample_list,names(sample_list),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

```r
$tables
  weight groupName
1     42    tables
2     24    tables
3     13    tables
4     31    tables
5      9    tables
6     27    tables

$chairs
  height groupName
1     18    chairs
2      6    chairs
3     34    chairs
4     37    chairs
5     36    chairs
6     49    chairs
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(dat, grp) cbind(dat, group_name = grp)[dat[[1]] > 20,], 
             sample_list, names(sample_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` with the function `data.frame` to add the names.

```
Map(`data.frame`, sample_list, groupName = names(sample_list))
#Map(`[<-`, sample_list, "groupName", value = names(sample_list)) #Alternative

#$tables
#   weight groupName
#1      22    tables
#2      12    tables
#3       9    tables
#4      26    tables
#5      39    tables
#6       6    tables
#7      31    tables
#8       9    tables
#9      39    tables
#10      4    tables
#11     37    tables
#12     30    tables
#13     20    tables
#14     35    tables
#15     31    tables
#16     46    tables
#17     44    tables
#18     30    tables
#19     12    tables
#20     46    tables
#
#$chairs
#   height groupName
#1      12    chairs
#2      17    chairs
#3      35    chairs
#4      40    chairs
#5      23    chairs
#6      21    chairs
#7      48    chairs
#8      24    chairs
#9      20    chairs
#10     41    chairs
#11     43    chairs
#12     45    chairs
#13     47    chairs
#14     13    chairs
#15     35    chairs
#16     32    chairs
#17     26    chairs
#18     34    chairs
#19     33    chairs
#20      8    chairs
```

In case it should also be subseted to those `>= 20`:

```
lapply(sample_list, function(x) x[x[,1] >= 20,, drop = FALSE])
```

When it should be done in one step I would use the way already posted by @akrun.